# Is 'edit' a correct term for the act of editing?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Can we refer to the action of editing as to an edit? For example as in this sentence, "I paid a lot to get that edit done, it was a long text". Or "Free photo edits for the first 100 customers".

Comment: Any particular reason why that _wouldn't_ be valid? Seems like you should check a few dictionaries first, and tell us what you find with an edit to your question.

Comment: Welcome to [english.se]. This question lacks basic information: why you ask and what you researched before asking.

Comment: The reason why I'm asking is that since English is not my first language I wasn't sure if it's the proper way to say it. I should have checked in the dictionary first. I tried to google it, but in most cases people refered to photo editing rather than photo edits so I was confused.

Comment: A question like this would probably be better received on the site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions). That said, even if you ask questions there, you should do basic research first, and share what you found when you ask your question. [Here's a great example of a non-native speaker](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105876) doing a splendid job of including prior research in the question. I suppose every question need not be _that_ thorough; still, there is much to emulate there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. From [the free dictionary:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/edit)

> edit, n. : An act or instance of editing: *made several last-minute edits for reasons of space.*

Comment: Thanks. I guess the correct order is dictionary first, than asking for help. Will remember next time.